# while Installing Microsoft Outlook Messenger in Ubuntu 12.04, getting error Object doesn't support this action

Tags: windows, outlook, ubuntu-12.04, wine

while Installing Microsoft Outlook Messenger in Ubuntu 12.04, getting error Object doesn't support this action

I used Wine for use Microsoft products in Ubuntu.

It is working perfectly in Ubuntu 10.04, but I don't know what happened in Ubuntu12.04,. I followed the same steps for installation that I took to install in Ubuntu 10.04,Other Microsoft products work prefectly in 12.04 like MS Office,Notepad, etc..

I got this error message while I'm trying to open Outlook using wine:

Run-time error '445' Object doesn't support this action.